# Difference between “new Foo()” and “&Foo()” as parameters

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing, new-operator

I have some questions concerning the difference between the keyword `new` and `&` in a certain context.

Let’s say this is my code:

```
struct Base {};
struct Foo : Base {};
struct Storage
{
    void save(Base * object) {}
    Base * content;
};

int main()
{
    Storage s1, s2;
    s1.save(new Foo());
    s2.save(&Foo());
}
```

After the execution of main, `s1` will hold a pointer to an object of type `Foo`. Yet `s2` will hold a pointer to an object of type `Base`. `s2.content` will only point towards an object of type `Foo` until the save method has finished execution.

Please correct me if I am wrong:

As far as I understand `new Foo()` creates a pointer to a new object of type `Foo`. `&Foo()` on the other hand first creates a new object of type `Foo` and then points to it.

What exactly is the difference between `new Foo()` and `&Foo()` then? Obviously both give you a pointer to an existing object of type `Foo`.

Why does the object created by `new Foo()` persist after execution of the save method whereas the object created via `&Foo()` does not?

May it be that `&Foo()` creates a temporary object, which will cease to exist after the execution of save? If yes, how can I prolong the life of the object created via `&Foo()` to make it live (at least) until the destruction of `s2`?

Edit 1:
Thank you very much for the quick answers! I'm simply using Visual Studio, so maybe `&Foo()` compiling is some Microsoft specific stuff...

Comment: You can't prolong the life of &Foo()

Comment: The most obvious difference would be that one compiles while the other doesn't... https://wandbox.org/permlink/qWn4eVLP3HWhIeGt

Comment: "how can I prolong the life of the object created via "&Foo()" ... that's what `new Foo()` is for.

Comment: "*Yet `s2` will hold a pointer to an object of type `Base`.*" - what makes you think that?

Comment: If you increased the warning level to at least 4, you'd get "warning C4238: nonstandard extension used: class rvalue used as lvalue".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> What exactly is the difference between "`new Foo()`" and "`&Foo()`" then?
>   Obviously both give you a pointer to an existing object of type Foo.
>
> Why does the object created by "`new Foo()`" persist after execution of
>   the save method whereas the object created via "`&Foo()`" does not?

---

### `new Foo()`

```
new Foo();
```

This creates a **dynamically-allocated** `Foo` object and returns a pointer pointing to that object. Dynamically-allocated objects will persist until they're explicitly deleted by the programmer:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
delete foo; // delete the object.
```

---

### `&Foo()`

```
Foo();
```

This creates a `Foo` object using **automatic-storage**. This means its lifetime, when the object is deleted, is decided by the scope that the object lives in:

```
{
  Foo foo{}; // foo lives in automatic storage.
} // end of scope, foo dies
```

In your case you are creating a new `Foo` object and you're passing the address of this anonymous object to `Storage::save`. This object will be destroyed at the end of the full expression. This basically means after `s2.save()` returns your object will be destroyed and the pointer pointing to it in `s2` will be dangling and dereferencing it will be undefined behaviour.

---

> If yes, how can I prolong the life of the object created via "&Foo()"
>   to make it live (at least) until the destruction of s2?

You can't. You probably want a smart pointer here such as `std::unique_ptr`.

---

Note that taking the address of a temporary is non-standard and thus this code is non-compliant to begin with. Your compiler is probably using an extension to allow it. MSVC is known for allowing this.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `Foo()` creates a new *temporary* object, and using the address-of operator `&` on that temporary object will result in a compiler error since it's not allowed to get the address of temporary objects like that (`Foo()` is an [*rvalue*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue) and the address-of operator can't be used on those).

With `new Foo` you create a *non* temporary object, and the result is a pointer to that object. The life-time of this object is until you explicitly `delete` it. And if you don't `delete` it then you will have a memory leak.

Comment: VS allows the binding for some reason

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `/W4` will warn about it. It's unfortunate that `/permissive-` doesn't make it a hard error though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's a *very* non-standard extension of MSVC++, unfortunately.